# Problems with icon inside input with type button

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, i have 2 buttons that you can see below. I need to add errorIcon but want to maintain the looks in button 1. Button 1 have browser specifik style, i have done nothing to button1.

[image: Pic of the buttons in firefox]

HTML:

```
Button1: <input type="button" value="Button1" />
Button2: <input type="button" class="errorIcon" value="Button2" />
```

CSS:

```
 .errorIcon{
    background: url("errorIcon.png") no-repeat scroll top left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 10px;
 }
```

Please note that i cant use example below because it triggers something i cant do anything about. Something else in the program runs on "button". This example gives me Button1 with error img as i want it to be.

```
<button><span class="errorIcon></span></button>
```

Comment: I don't think that would happen, as Windows 7 UI won't allow this! :) You can create a totally custom button which would have the image too..

Comment: You might try with `::before` pseudo element

Comment: Ok but how can the custom button resize if the text i   "SHORT" or "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG" if it is an image?  Doesnt sound right

Comment: does ::before work in IE8?

Comment: You can use `:before` (pseudo-class) for IE8. But what are you trying to achieve exactly? Put a red cross at the top left of the button, while keeping the label? Or replace the whole background?

Comment: Forget about pseudo-class or pseudo-element on `input`, it doesn't seems to work on all of them.

Comment: I want to add the red cross on one of the buttons but maintain the same browser specific styles. It works if you have <button><span class="errorIcon></span></button> but i cant use this because it triggers something old and hairy in the system ;-)

Comment: Why are you setting `width:10px` for that button? Clearly the value `Button2` won’t fit into that width. Please explain what you actually want to achieve and what the problems are.

Comment: Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style both buttons cause of you leave first button unstyled it will change look depending on browser and system. So style both of them

You can style button using gradients like this
http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/

And add image via ::before or ::after

Comment: I think you answered different question, definitely not this one :) _I need to add errorIcon but want to maintain the looks in button 1._ I would change _the looks in button 1_ to _the looks of button 1_ and it would make more sense

Comment: Then I must admit I cannot understand the question(

Comment: You can add icon via ::before and ::after... Bigood already have said this though)

Comment: Please correct me if the question is wrong, try reading it again ;-)

Comment: .errorIcon:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
width: 52px;
height: 52px;
left: 3px;
backgound:transparent url(x-mark.png) no-repeat 0px 0px; 
}
(just insert the position and background our need)